# Is it valid to have finally block without try and catch?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to use the finally block without using the try/catch blocks but getting the error in Eclipse.

Can I use the finally block without using the try/catch blocks?

Comment: Even if you could put a `finally` without a `try` how would you want your `finally` to behave if you use a `goto` to skip over the `finally` statement? `finally` is only relevant to the code it is marked to be relevant with using the `try` statement. Otherwise the behavior would be very annoying.

Comment: Do you mean what is the use case of try-with-finally, with out using catch block? I think you can't use only "finally". it should be with some try block.

Answer (score 22):

`finally` should have atleast a `try` block, `catch` is optional. The point of finally blocks is to make sure stuff gets cleaned up whether an exception is thrown or not. As per the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> A finally clause ensures that the finally block is executed **after the try block and any catch block** that might be executed, no matter how control leaves the try block or catch block.

Hence a `finally` should always be preceded by a `try` block.

Answer (score 8):

You must have a `try` block with a `finally` block. The `try` block defines which lines of code will be followed by the `finally` code. If an exception is thrown prior to the `try` block, the `finally` code will not execute.

Adding `catch` blocks is optional:

```
try {

  // something

} finally {
  // guaranteed to run if execution enters the try block
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If an exception is thrown prior to the try block, the finally code will not execute. **The finally block always executes when the try block exits. So you can use finally without catch but you must use try.**

Comment: Almost exact answer given 6 years prioer by stinepike

Answer (score 5):

```
try {
    // Block of code with multiple exit points
}
finally {
    // Block of code that must always be executed when the try block
    // is exited, no matter how the try block is exited
}
```

Comment: you should add an explanation

Answer (score 3):

The finally block always executes when the try block exits. So you can use finally without catch but you must use try.

For more details check [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) here

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you cannot have a `finally` without a `try` is because you *could* have multiple `finally` statements in the same scope and the `try` indicates what block of code the `finally` pertains to in case an error occurs.

Another interesting feature of the `finally` is that it must execute no matter what when the `try` is entered. For example what if you use a `goto` to skip over your `finally` statement? If the `goto` is inside of the `try` it will execute the `finally` statement however if the `goto` is above/outside the `try` statement then it will skip the `finally` code. `finally` is relevant only to the code that is surrounded in the `try`. If you have no try then the `finally` is not relevant to anything.

Answer (score 1):

- A try statement should have either catch block or finally block, it
  can       have both blocks.
- We can’t write any code between try-catch-finally    block.
- We can’t have catch or finally clause without a try statement.
- We can have multiple catch blocks with a single try statement.try-catch blocks can be nested similar to if-else statements.
- We can have only one finally block with a try-catch    statement.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle Trails:

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs.

From the above statement, you cannot have finally block alone on its own. below are the combinations allowed.

1. try 
          catch
               finally
2. try 
           catch
3. try 
              finally

Answer (score 0):

The code within the `finally` block is guaranteed to execute if program control flow enters the corresponding `try` block. So it makes no sense to have a `finally` without a `try`.

The only exception to this is if the program encounters a `System.exit(...)` call before the `finally` block, as that shuts down the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't

you can use `Try-catch-finally` or `try-finally`

```
 try {

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    finally{

    }
```

or

```
try {

    }
    finally{

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using only try block is not correct.
- Try block can be used with only one block from catch or finally
  block.
- You can use try block with catch and finally.If you use finally block
  with try block then catch block become optional.